# Dockerfile its not copying all files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a discord.py bot on a docker container. But when I'm running the container, docker says that I'm "missing a module". The `Dockerfile` its not copying all the files/folders from the source code.

This is my directory:

[image]

These are the contents of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  bot:
    build: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./.env:/usr/src/app/.env
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:bullseye

WORKDIR /usr/app/src

COPY bot bot

CMD ["python", "-m", "bot"]
```

When I run `# sudo docker compose up` It fails with the following log:
[image]

Checking the docker image files, it seems like its copying all the contents inside of the `bot` folder, but its not copying the folder itself.

[image]

The code works fine if I run it outside of the container, so is not related to this discord bot code.

How can I fix this?
This is my first docker container I'm new really with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```
COPY bot bot/
```

By design, `COPY` always copies the contents of the directory if the source is a directory, and by adding the trailing `/` to the destination you tell `docker` that the destination is a directory, so it will create it for you if needed.

See [the full documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

Comment: Yes that was, tyvm!